# Give the order of nucleophilic addition reaction in the following -

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, inductive-effect

[image]
I am confused that whether we should take only inductive or hyperconjugation effect also into consideration while finding the order. As the answer in the book is only according to inductive effect . Will hyperconjugation effect come into play or not ?
If we take hyperconjugation effect then order must be 2>4>3>1.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: how will these molecules react to the presence of a nucleophile (which would add to the more electrophilic center, i.e. the carbonyl carbon atom)?

The more the carbon atom of the carbonyl group has a partial positive charge, the more it is susceptible to be attacked by a nucleophile, so the problem is to compare the relative positive charge on the carbonyl carbon atom between those molecules.

Remember that an alkyl group has an electron-donating effect AND that a longer alkyl group has more electron-donating effect.

With all that, you should be able to answer your problem.

Comment: Yes I understand, but i am asking that won't hyperconjugation have any role . As more the hyperconjugation structures lesser will be the positive charge on carbon hence less reactive.

Comment: Structure 4 have more hyperconjugation than 2, while 2nd have more inductive effect. And hyperconjugation> inductive